# Yank part of multiple lines and paste

Tags: vim

Is there a way I can select a portion of multiple lines in vim and then paste them at the end of another block of lines.  For instance if I want everything after the equal sign from:

```
qw=12345
er=23435
```

and pasted into:

```
ty=
ui=
```

What would I have to do?

This seems real simple, but for some reason, I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [block selection mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405024930/http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2005/02/28/vim-tip-of-the-week-visual-select-block-mode/).

Please note the different keybinding for Windows platforms.

Comment: Do you recommend something else if one of the lines had three letters before the equal sign?

Comment: @thequerist: Nope, except perhaps `^V3l`, `^Ve`, `^Vt=`, `^V}ot=` etc. to get the block selection; it's the joy of Vim's text object motions